# Can I change an IEC visa to an employer sponsored visa?

Tags: canada, visa-change, working-holiday-visas

I was thinking about moving to Canada for a while under the IEC (working holiday) visa.

I'm a software engineer by trade and would look for work in that industry.

If I fall in love with the work / the employer wants me to stay - can I change my status / visa to an employer sponsored visa so I can stay longer than the IEC visa?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. [Can I apply for a work permit from inside Canada?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=172&top=17) is very clear in this: getting a work permit from inside Canada is very rarely allowed. You could check the [Extend or change your work permit – International Experience Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/extend/iec.asp) page as well but from the very brief description you gave us I would think the answer is no here as well.